# Making my 2 Motors (with wheels) take a smooth left as its tracking the left side using a range sensor

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, sensors

So to jump right into it, I currently have my setup of using a urg laser sensor, a arduino pro mini (slave), a raspberry pi (master) and Sabertooth 2x12 PWM controlling 2 motors.

btw i am programming in cpp

I got everything all setup, and using the laser sensor data that I obtain from the urg laser sensor I am able to get the front, left, right, frontleft, front right, backleft, and backright of my little system that is being driven by 2 wheel drive( motor ) and 2 variable wheels in the front.

I am tracking a obsolete wall, and its suppose to take a left when the backleft sensor detects nothing.

It goes great! until it makes a turn (turn is set to 45 when it detects, to make a u turn around the obsolete wall) and stops midway, because the backleft is detecting the wall still halfway it turns. Its hard to explain unless you visualize it.

which i will try via asci

```
--------------------
     ---->           [] <-- my device (backleft detects nothing at this point)
```

mid turn

```
-------------------- [] <-- it now detects a backleft and stops
```

anyway to keep make it do a smooth left turn without putting a delay. I want to make it as seamless as possible. Already implented PID so this is the last part :(

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've initiated turning you probably need to start looking at the front-left sensor value, instead of the back-left. Perhaps continue turning until the front-left is at an appropriately low value, then start moving forwards. You may need to continue to correct steering after turning until the front-left and back-left sensors give the same distance from the wall (assuming you want to end up parallel).

Comment: i'll definitely try this tomorrow once i am in my lab. the only problem is its getting data from backleft currently, and doesnt switch between back and front left once it already initiates the turn. if it switches, it will always try to take a left, instead of going forward. this is one of the troubles of making the system fully autonomous